# Adapter causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview

Im facing some memory leak trouble. At first I thought, it might be `WeakReference` or `Listeners`, but then I intentionally set them null in constructor (no point of 'em) to ensure, that memory leak is caused by some other problem. I'm pretty sure it's somewhere inside my `OnCreateViewHolder` or `OnBindViewHolder` methods.

```
public class OutterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<...> data;
private InnerAdapter innerAdapter;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
private WeakReference<Activity> reference;

public OutterAdapter (List<..> dataList,
                       Activity activity,
                       ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    data = dataList;
    itemClickListener = itemClickListener= null;
    //mActivityReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == A)
        return new AViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, null));
    else
        return new BViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, null));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Item item = data.get(position);
    if (holder instanceof AViewHolder) {
        ViewPager vP = ((AViewHolder) holder).mViewPager;
        vP.setAdapter(newXAdapter(data,/*clickListener*/null));
        CirclePageIndicator pageIndicator = ((AViewHolder) holder).mIndicator;
        pageIndicator.setViewPager(vP);
    } else {
        BViewHolder bViewHolder = (BViewHolder) holder;
        bViewHolder.getTitleView().setText(item.getTitle());
        new InnerAdapter(item, /*clickListener*/ null);
        bViewHolder.getRecyclerView().setAdapter(innerAdapter);
    }
}
```

If you didn't understand from code, then - I've a nested recyclerview. In `OutterAdapter's` I create `InnerAdapter` by `setAdapter(innerAdapter);` in `OnBindViewHolder`. Yes, might not be the best scenerio for nested recyclerviews, but I want to understand what is the thing that is leaking? What causes this? In profiler, I see that all `OutterAdapter` values are really `null` (as I set them), but `OutterAdapter` has many instances switching/destroying views where it should be only 1 or none. `InnerAdapter` usually has x2 count of `OutterAdapter`. I tried to `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` of parent views `onDestroy()` method, but it did nothing, same goes to different variations of nulling these UI widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), add this to your app and you'll get a notification whenever there is a memory leak. It also gives hints on what might be causing it.

Just a suggetion from me will be to switch the nersted view pager with recyclerview with snap helper and [overflow indicator](https://github.com/intik/overflow-pager-indicator).

Comment: LeakCanary didn't give much more information I had previously. Second suggestion is not possible for my case. Any other ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There is a method public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder); in the RecyclerAdapter. There you can null anything that might be leaking. Don't forget to init things on rebinding.

Comment: Well, that only works when view is recycled, but if I open fragment and then change to other and so forth - this function will not hit

Comment: Are you nulling the views of the fragments onDestroyView?